# How to make outside of framework implement some specifc method

Tags: ios, swift

I built a framework myself, and in the framework, I have a http request
that needs to use dynamic parameters.

The whole implementation does not need the framework's user to implement anything but the dynamic parameters.

So, my question is: How can I get the parameters?

Comment: Can you please post some related code?

Comment: delegate methods? maybe show some pseudo code of what you mean, or some actual code

Comment: @anhtu and Fonix  sorry, i don't have any code yet. It's just an idea flashed in my mind. Thx for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the framework design, you might either

- need a Singleton object that holds the framework's configuration and a configuration-method must be called by the user before any other API use.

  Thus, the methods using the data can access it when they need it throughout the framework.
- Pass the arguments as actual arguments to the methods that actually need this data.
- Have the objects using the data store the data for object lifetime and have the user use a factory that configures the objects accordingly.

Comment: Thx for the answer! I were thinking that maybe i can read a file with JSON or other data in the project that use the framework. But after a while, i thought maybe the start point was wrong.  The whole idea was wrong.^_^